# ¿Como mostrar y ocultar contraseña de edittext tipo password?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Este es mi diseño android xml, para introducir contraseñas

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http:// schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:hint="Introduce tu contraseña" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

 </ LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es introducir los iconos en mi edittext y programar los dos iconos en el mismo edittext para mostrar y ocultar contraseña, de la siguiente manera que al dar click y escribir siempre muestre la contraseña y si la quiero ocultar presiono en el icono y que sea reversible, si otra vez la quiero volver a ver me muestre dando click en el icono
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes que cambiar el tipo de input de password a normal y viseversa, asi pasa tambien con el icono, puedes usar una variable booleana para distingir el estado de los iconos y el input asi con un if else puedes alternarlos al dar click en el icono. PD: seria bueno que especificaras en que lenguaje estas programando. y compartir almenos

Comment: no veo por que usas la etiqueta JavaScript cuando tu pregunta claramente es sobre Java

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `TextInputLayout` y este ya tiene una opcion:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/edtPassText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyAppTheme.TextInputLayout"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/icon_selector"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Contraseña:"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Crea un `dreawable xml` con el nombre `icon_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/baseline_visibility_black_18dp" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/baseline_visibility_off_black_18dp"/>
</selector>
```

Recuerda tener en tus dependencias:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' //depende de tu configuracion de proyecto
```

Comment: Si en lugar de usar los iconos del ojo, quisiera usar un texto que en el lugar del icono diga mostrar, ocultar como lograría hacer eso posible ...gracias

Answer (score 1):

En tu activity declara una variable al inicio de la clase:

```
private boolean esVisible;
```

Despues pon esto para controlar cuando se oculta y cuando se muestra:

```
visible.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!esVisible) {
            password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            esVisible = true;
            ///aqui puedes cambiar el texto del boton, o textview, o cambiar la imagen de un imageView.
        }
        else {
            password.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            esVisible = false;
            ///aqui puedes cambiar el texto del boton, o textview, o cambiar la imagen de un imageView.
        }
    }
});
```

La variable **visible** la cual lleva el `onClickListener();` puede ser cualquier  componente como un **TextView**, un **ImageView** o un **Button**, con el cual quieres controlar si se muestra o se oculta la contraseña.

La variable **password** es el EditText que tiene la contraseña.

Answer (score 1):

hay una forma fácil de hacer esto, yo lo utilizo y me funciona muy bien:
(coloca en el XML y te saldrá)

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.472"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edUsuario"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="257dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvMIP"
            android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Ingrese Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

Y te mostrar con el ojito para el ocultes la contraseña y poder mostrarla, asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estaba buscando como resolver esto y no encontré mucha información y ninguna forma fácil de hacerlo, así que hizo lo siguiente para resolverlo:

```
private void MostrarClave() {
    hide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hiden);
    Key = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //145 Texto sin Ocultar
            //129 Texto Oculto
            int n = Key.getInputType();
            if (n == 129) {
                Key.setInputType(145);
            } else {
                Key.setInputType(129);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Obtuve los valores de ambos controles y los modifico en tiempo de ejecución con el evento clicklistener del checkbox, espero ayudar a alguien.